# How to load/replace an entire DIV from an external HTML file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have the following index.html page set-up:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar_menu">
      </div>
      <div id="thecontent">
        <div id="page_banner">
        </div>
        <div id="page_content">
        </div>
        <div id="page_footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In addition to this, I have several individual .html files that reflect an option in my sidebar menu, so when the user first lands on the page, they will see index.html file based on the above setup, ie. shows header/menu/the content and footer.

My question is, when the user clicks on say the "About Us" menu option, I actually want to just replace "thecontent" div with the contents of my about-us.html file but without reloading the header and sidebar menu. I just want the entire div "thecontent" to be replaced with the div "thecontent" from my about-us.html file.

Is this possible as like I said, I have several individual .html files and really don't want to duplicate code like my sidebar menu in every page as only my content will be changing based on menu selection.

I looked at jQuery.load() from [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/).

I think though this will not work. Also saw the .replacewith() but unsure if this is correct and if it is, unsure how to use in my scenario to go off and replace div with an external .html file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's load method has a special syntax that allows you to select what content you want to load from the URL you provide. You simply specify a CSS selector after your URL.
(Read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), under "Loading Page Fragments")

For example:

```
$("#thecontent").load("about-us.html #thecontent");
```

### Hosted demo:

http://jsbin.com/uvera3 (Editable via http://jsbin.com/uvera3/edit)

Comment: if you do this you have sonthing like html>body>thecontent>thecontent
and we expect to have juste html>body>thecontent

Comment: @BenZen, you can avoid the nesting of #thecontent by using ``$("#thecontent").load("about-us.html #thecontent>*");`` which will extract only the child elements of #thecontent and inject them into the existing #thecontent element.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try load? It's exactly what you want:

```
$('#thecontent`').load('about-us.html');
```

bound to a link:

```
$(function() {
    $("#aboutuslink").click(function(){
          $('#thecontent`').load('about-us.html');
         return false;
    }) ;
});
<a href="#" id="aboutuslink">About Us</a>
```

At http://api.jquery.com/load/  scroll down to the part about loading page fragments.

Comment: Hi Lee. Tried this but as I mentioned below to jAndy, replaced my whole index.html file + sidebar menu, which isn't what I want?

Answer (score 0):

> **Description**: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Thats straight out of the jQuery documentation for `.load()` which will do **exactly** what you want.

```
$('#thecontent').load('/whereever/about-us.html');
```

All done, Thanks!

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Hi, actually did use the .load() call but this actually replaced my whole index.html with the complete contents of my about-us.html file, including the sidebar menu, which my about-us.html file makes no reference to - any ideas?

Comment: @tonsils i'm having this same issue - trying to load a navbar in my index.html is completely wiping out everything else in my index.html - did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the server includes the HTML for the layer that is going to be replaced, you could do something like this:

```
$.get('/server-side.html', function(data)
{
    $('#content').html($(data).html());
});
```

Assuming that /server-side.html returns something like this:

```
<div id="content">
    YOUR CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Hope that it helps. Regards.