# .load not working for changing content of div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change the content of a specific div on an onclick event using .load for some reason it is not working and I do not know why. I am trying to replicate the the exact same thing that was asked in this posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432553/how-to-load-replace-an-entire-div-from-an-external-html-file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

$('#electric').bind('click',function(){
    $("#chart_div").load("new_content.html");
 });
});

</script>
```

html

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="chart_div">hello</div>
</div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
    <a id="electric" href="#">Electric link</a>
    <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Gas</a>
</ul>
```

new_content.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>New Content!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: $("#chart_div").load("new_content.html"); Thats It !!!!

Comment: Are you running this from your local drive as a file system call?  or through an app/web server?

Comment: I am running this from my local drive.

Comment: You're missing `http:` in `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: This looks like a Dom not loaded yet problem and there is no tag in `new_content.html` with id `chart_div`

Comment: @ocat hey mate check my answer you forget to wrap code inside document.ready

Comment: @ocat `I am running this from my local drive.` you should try on local webserver.

Comment: For whatever reason .live was not working but .bind did work.

Answer (score 1):

you have to .ready function to run click event....because when document is ready then only you can handle click event

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#electric").click(function(e){
 $("#chart_div").load("new_content.html");
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

for 1.6

```
$('#electric').live('click',function(){
//your code
});
```

use on() from 1.9 version..

```
$(document).on('click','#electric',function(){
//your code..
});
```

Comment: Umm, is `.on()` supported in version 1.6.1? Because according to the jQuery link, that's the version the OP is using.

Comment: @Jai, this is a perfectly valid answer. Formatting is fine. I would say that your answer however, would do nothing for the OP. There is no default event to prevent.

Comment: @jadec its fine but that is just preventing the jump which documents get when click on any link on page.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you meant the StackOverflow docs. My bad... :)

Comment: @jacedc why use `live` though.

Comment: It's better than `.click()` (in some cases when you need live DOM interaction), and version 1.6.1 does not support `.on()`.

Comment: `.live()` should be used when you want to click a element which is dynamically created or loaded via `ajax` and in the OP's question this seems useless, although will work but `.click()` is fine here.

Comment: **[Please avoid extended discussions in comments]**. So I guess we should wrap this up, however, `.click()` has no "live" DOM interaction, which can be useful, especially if dynamically loading new content.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#electric").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#chart_div").load("new_content.html");
    });
  });
</script>
```

You don't need to target `#chart_div` because it's not in the `new_content.html`.

Comment: Well, I did not downvote, but to shed some light here, passing `e.preventDefault()` does nothing. However, +1 for corrected targetting of `#chart_div`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do more , just

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#electric").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#chart_div").load("new_content.html");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of changes ,

You are missing http: in you script tag ,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

trigger your script on "ON" event

```
$(function (){
    $("#electric").on('click',function(){
      $("#chart_div").load("new_content.html #chart_div");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(function (){` is missing from code. Wrap your code inside `document.ready` that you did not do.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#electric").on('click',function()
    {
        $("#chart_div").load("new_content.html #chart_div");
    });
});
```